# Python 2.7: Syntax Error. Newlines characters within string literals

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am working on a project using Python 2.7 and I am attempting to output a few string literals with objects. Ideally, each string literal should jump to the next line after each `\n` newline character.

I am still learning and am a novice programmer, so if I need to include more information please let me know and I will edit the question.

Here is what I am working on:

```
    output = (
        f"\nFinancial Analysis\n"
        f"----------------------------\n"
        f"Total Months: {total_months}\n"
        f"Total Revenue: ${total_revenue}\n"
        f"Average Revenue Change: ${revenue_avg}\n"
        f"Greatest Increase in Revenue: {greatest_increase[0]}(${greatest_increase[1]})\n"
        f"Greatest Decrease in Revenue: {greatest_decrease[0]} (${greatest_decrease[1]})\n")
```

Each time I run my script in the terminal, I receive the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(base) Grants-MacBook-Pro-2:PyBank grant$ python PyBank.py
File "PyBank.py", line 45
f"\nFinancial Analysis\n"
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I can tweak my code and correct the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Copy and paste the real error message, don't summarize it. What you posted isn't even in the code. Also this code works fine on my machine

Comment: Thank you. I just added the error message.

Comment: It looks like you are not running this on Python >=3.6. Type `python -V` to confirm.

Comment: You're right. It's running in Python 2.7. I apologize for the confusion. I just edited the question to reflect.

Comment: At this stage *you really should not be devoting time an effort to learning Python 2.7.* You have already gotten yourself bogged down in one version confusion and if you continue that will get worse before it gets better. End-of-life for Python 2.7 is 1 January 2020 and while some of us still have pressing reasons to go on coding in 2.7, I have trouble believing that you do. *Please* consider dumping your 2.7 installation.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 doesn't have f-strings. Switch to 3.6+ or use `.format()` instead

For example you need to replace

```
f"Total Months: {total_months}\n"
```

with

```
"Total Months: {}\n".format(total_months)
```